# Is relation between this_thread::sleep_for and chrono clocks specified by C++11 standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Consider following code:

```cpp
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
typedef std::intmax_t intmax_type;

steady_clock::time_point start = steady_clock::now();

this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(25000));

steady_clock::duration dur = steady_clock::now() - start;

intmax_type desired_dur = duration_cast<milliseconds>(dur).count();

if(desired_dur < intmax_type(25000))
    std::cout << "WTF happend there?" << std::endl;
```

According to standard `std::this_thread::sleep_for(sleep_duration)` may block for longer than `sleep_duration` due to scheduling or resource contention delays but *at least* it blocks thread execution for the specified `sleep_duration`.

There may be situation when the thread actually sleeps for specified duration but due to `std::chrono::steady_clock` or `std::chrono::system_clock` using different OS clocks than `sleep_for` implementation (different granularity f.e.) time period measurement gives us different result than actual sleep time was.

My question is:

Is it prohibited by C++11 standard for condition `if(desired_dur < intmax_type(25000))` to happen? If so provide the exact quotes please.

Answer (score 2):

It is prohibited by C++11/14/17/20 for `desired_dur < intmax_type(25000)` to be `true`.

[Here is the spec for `this_thread::sleep_for`](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.thread.this#7):

> *Effects:* Blocks the calling thread for the relative timeout (32.2.4) specified by `rel_time`.

[The reference to 32.2.4 is here.](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.req.timing)  This is a very long-winded section which defines `rel_time` as a *relative timeout*.  Probably the most important paragraph is p3:

> The functions whose names end in `_for` take an argument that
> specifies a duration. These functions produce relative timeouts.
> Implementations should use a steady clock to measure time for these
> functions.<sup>326</sup> Given a duration argument *D<sub>t</sub>*,
> the real-time duration of the timeout is *D<sub>t</sub>* +
> *D<sub>i</sub>* + *D<sub>m</sub>*.
>
> <sup>326)</sup> All implementations for which standard time units are meaningful must necessarily have a steady clock within their hardware implementation.

The section defines *D<sub>i</sub>* as a “quality of implementation” delay, and *D<sub>m</sub>* as a “quality of management” delay.  These definitions imply (by the use of "delay") that they are non-negative quantities of time duration.

The term "steady clock" is never actually defined but [the standard does say this about `steady_clock`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.steady#1):

> Objects of class `steady_clock` represent clocks for which values of
> `time_point` never decrease as physical time advances and for which
> values of `time_point` advance at a steady rate relative to real time.
> That is, the clock may not be adjusted.

The use of the word "should" in the sentence:

> Implementations should use a steady clock

is wiggle room.  "should" means:

> We really want you to, but you don't have to.  You can still call yourself conforming if you don't.

"should" is used instead of "shall" here because there is no such thing as a perfect clock, especially inside your consumer grade computer.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer however I do not see why is it prohibited by standard. First of all consider 'sleep_for' using not monotonic clock (should not shall, yes?) - every OS time shift may lead to inaccuracy in the result, right? Then - what if we use 'chrono::system_clock' instead of steady for time measurement? And last but not least - what if 'sleep_for' implementation uses Monotonic Clock №1, but 'chrono::steady_clock' uses Monotonic Clock №2 - should it be synchronised by standard or not? If not - there lies the question asked.

Comment: Writing a standards spec is very hard.  For anything in the standard that is relatively complex, there's always a way to read the standard that allows implementations to do crazy things.  So one also has to look at the intent of the wording under "reasonable interpretations".  Also there are no standards police.  An implementation is ultimately answerable to no one but its customers.  If an implementation is sufficiently non-conforming as judged by its customers (and if the customers value conformity), then it goes out of business.

Comment: Ultimately the question is:  If an implementation does something you believe is incorrect, can you cite the standard to support your bug report?  And bugs do happen in this very area.  I know of one implementation that rounds `rel_time` down instead of up to the next "sleepable" duration precision. I'm not sure if this bug is fixed yet or not.

Comment: Sorry but you are talking about bugs in implementations and some "C++ standard way"/ "common sense" of implementing std library. Sure it would be odd if time measurements of exact same std library with 'chrono' clocks will return different result (less) than actual sleep time was for 'this_thread::sleep_for'. My question is however if or why not it is prohibited by C++11 standard for implementation to have such an odd behaviour. That's it.

Comment: To more fully understand your objection to the current wording I need to know how you would improve it.  The best way to suggest improved wording for the standard is to submit an issue with proposed wording.  Everyone can do so (like an open-source project).  Here are detailed instructions on how to do so:  http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#submit_issue

Comment: I'm not objecting wording of standard I just point out that your answer "

It is prohibited by C++11/14/17/20 for desired_dur < intmax_type(25000) to be true." is not backed up with standard quotes. The paragraph and quotes you refer to in your answer do not prohibit such behaviour, at max - "strongly recommend". What I'm trying to understand - is there any more quotes in standard that actually support your first statement or this is not specified?

Comment: Perhaps it would help to direct you to the paper that introduced the wording to prevent this problem: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3191.htm  This paper includes more rationale and logic behind the current wording.